# calculate sum of values in sql (Distinct/Case Statement)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, distinct

I want to build a SQL query which will eliminate duplicate values `DISTINCT` then `Sum` then print column value as header and obtains the result

Sample data :-

```
ID  TYPE    Values
A   FLM     00:34:09
A   FLM     16:03:19
A   SLM     00:37:48
B   FLM     00:42:47
B   SLM     01:14:56
C   SLM     01:00:52
C   SLM     00:37:48
```

I want to do `Sum of Values` of same `TYPE` for each `ID` then display according to `Type`

Expected output :

```
ID  FLM         SLM
A   16:37:28    00:37:48
B   00:42:47    01:14:56
C   NULL        01:38:40
```

What I am getting

```
ID  FLM         SLM
A   01:38:40    NULL
A   NULL        00:37:48
B   00:42:47    NULL
B   NULL        01:14:56
C   NULL        01:38:40
```

Here I am able to do a sum of each type but result is showing in two different rows rather than single row.

My query :

```
Select Distinct ID
    CASE 
        When Type='SLM' 
        Then    STR(SUM(DateDiff(s,[Start Date],[End Date]))/3600) + 
                RIGHT(CONVERT(char(8),DATEADD(s,SUM(DateDiff(s,[Start Date],[End Date])),0),108),6)
    End[FLM],
    CASE    
        When Type='SLM' 
        Then    STR(SUM(DateDiff(s,[Start Date],[End Date]))/3600) + 
                RIGHT(CONVERT(char(8),DATEADD(s,SUM(DateDiff(s,[Start Date],[End Date])),0),108),6)
    End[SLM],

From #_TicketType GROUP BY ID,Type
```

P.S. using column `[Start Date],[End Date]` of datatype `DateTime` I am getting column `Values` in sample data table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Updated) Remove `Type` from your `group by`, and move the CASE inside the SUM, like so:

```
Select ID,
    STR(SUM(CASE Type WHEN 'FLM' THEN DateDiff(s,[Start Date],[End Date]) END)/3600) +
    RIGHT(CONVERT(char(8),DATEADD(s,SUM(CASE Type WHEN 'FLM' THEN DateDiff(s,[Start Date],[End Date]) END),0),108),6) [FLM],
    STR(SUM(CASE Type WHEN 'SLM' THEN DateDiff(s,[Start Date],[End Date]) END)/3600) +
    RIGHT(CONVERT(char(8),DATEADD(s,SUM(CASE Type WHEN 'SLM' THEN DateDiff(s,[Start Date],[End Date]) END),0),108),6) [SLM]
From #_TicketType 
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 66
Column '#_TicketType.Type' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @SagarDumbre: I have updated the query to move the `case` condition inside the `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUM() function on the entire CASE expression

```
SELECT ID,
    STR(SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'FLM' 
                 THEN DATEDIFF(s,[Start Date],[End Date]) 
            END) /3600) +
    RIGHT(CONVERT(char(8),DATEADD(s, SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'FLM' 
                                   THEN DATEDIFF(s,[Start Date],[End Date]) END),0)
                              ,108),6) AS [FLM],                                  
    STR(SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'SLM' 
                 THEN DATEDIFF(s,[Start Date],[End Date])
            END)) /3600 + 
    RIGHT(CONVERT(char(8),DATEADD(s, SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'SLM' 
                                   THEN DATEDIFF(s,[Start Date],[End Date]) END),0)
                              ,108),6) AS [SLM]
FROM #_TicketType 
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 134
Operand data type datetime is invalid for sum operator.